# When analog stick looks down and jump button is pressed then fall through a platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Im making a mobile 2d game in unity. As the title says i'm trying to make it so when the player has the analog stick looking down and jump button is pressed instead of jumping it should just fall through. As of right now the platform does have the platform effector 2d component all set up but the thing i want to do just doesnt work. Here are the 2 scripts i have as of right now.

Player Controller script

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnalogStick movementJoystick;
    public float playerSpeed;
    public float smoothTime = 0.1f;
    public float smoothSpeedMultiplier = 1.5f;
    public float jumpForce = 8f;
    public float waiting;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    public Collider2D playerCollider;
    public GameObject Box;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float currentVelocity;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool isJumping;
    private float verticalInput;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            HandleJumpButtonClicked();
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float horizontalInput = movementJoystick.joystickVec.x;
        Move(horizontalInput);

        if (isJumping)
        {
            Jump();
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    public void Move(float horizontalInput)
    {
        float targetVelocity = horizontalInput * playerSpeed;
        float smoothSpeed = smoothSpeedMultiplier * Mathf.Abs(targetVelocity);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.SmoothDamp(rb.velocity.x, targetVelocity, ref currentVelocity, smoothTime, smoothSpeed), rb.velocity.y);
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
        return colliders.Length > 0;
    }

    public float GetVerticalInput()
    {
        return movementJoystick.joystickVec.y;
    }

    public void VerticalInput(float input)
    {
        verticalInput = input;
    }

    public void HandleJumpButtonClicked()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
        bool fallThroughPlatform = false;

        foreach (Collider2D collider in colliders)
        {
            if (collider.CompareTag("OneWayPlatform") && verticalInput < -0.5f)
            {
                fallThroughPlatform = true;
                StartCoroutine(FallTimer());
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!fallThroughPlatform)
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FallTimer()
    {
        playerCollider.enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiting);
        playerCollider.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

then the Analog stick script for the x and y movement of the joystick.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class AnalogStick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject joystick;
    public GameObject joystickBG;
    public Vector2 joystickVec;
    private Vector2 joystickTouchPos;
    private Vector2 joystickOriginalPos;
    private float joystickRadius;
    public PlayerController playerController; // Reference to the player controller script

    void Start()
    {
        joystickOriginalPos = joystickBG.transform.position;
        joystickRadius = joystickBG.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y / 4;
    }

    public void PointerDown()
    {
        joystick.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
        joystickBG.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
        joystickTouchPos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    
    public void Drag(BaseEventData baseEventData)
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = baseEventData as PointerEventData;
        Vector2 dragPos = pointerEventData.position;
        joystickVec = (dragPos - joystickTouchPos).normalized;

        float joystickDist = Vector2.Distance(dragPos, joystickTouchPos);

        if(joystickDist < joystickRadius)
        {
            joystick.transform.position = joystickTouchPos + joystickVec * joystickDist;
        }
        else
        {
            joystick.transform.position = joystickTouchPos + joystickVec * joystickRadius;
        }
        
        UpdatePlayerMovement(joystickVec.x, joystickVec.y);
    }

    public void PointerUp()
    {
        joystickVec = Vector2.zero;
        joystick.transform.position = joystickOriginalPos;
        joystickBG.transform.position = joystickOriginalPos;
        
        UpdatePlayerMovement(0f, 0f);
    }

    private void UpdatePlayerMovement(float horizontalInput, float verticalInput)
    {
        playerController.Move(horizontalInput);
        playerController.VerticalInput(verticalInput);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why but for some reason it just doesnt work. When i put the analog stick down and then jump it just does nothing. It jumps if its in the top which is what i want it to do but the other thing doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: I have no idea about the code but why are using one button for two actions? I suggest creating another (down dash?) button, it'll make the code clearer and overall better player experience